# Can I restrict the search to a specific date range?

Tags: solr

I want to get all results AFTER a given date, can you do this with solr?

(http://lucene.apache.org/solr/)

Right now the results are search the entire result set, I want to filter for anything after a given date.

**Update**
This isn't working for me yet.

My returned doc:

trying:

http://www.example.com:8085/solr/select/?q=test&version=2.2&start=0&rows=10&indent=on&indexed_at:2009-08-27T13%3A15%3A27.73Z

```
<doc>
<str name="apptype">Forum</str>
<str name="collapse">forum:334</str>
<str name="content"> testing </str>
<str name="contentid">357</str>
<str name="createdby">some_user</str>
<str name="date">20090819</str>
<str name="dummy_id">1</str>
<int name="group">5</int>
<date name="indexed_at">2009-08-25T16:48:45.121Z</date>
<str name="rating">000.0</str>
<str name="rawcontent"><p>testing</p></str>
−
<arr name="roles">
<str>1</str>
<str>2</str>
<str>3</str>
<str>4</str>
<str>14</str>
<str>15</str>
<str>16</str>
</arr>
<int name="section">79</int>
<int name="thread">334</int>
<str name="title">testing</str>
<str name="titlesort">testing</str>
<str name="type">forum</str>
−
<str name="unique_id">
BLAHBLAH|357
</str>
<str name="url">/blahey/f/79/p/334/357.aspx#357</str>
<str name="user">21625</str>
<str name="username">some_user</str>
</doc>
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can I assume you have a field with the date value you want to filter on. Then you do

```
yourdatefield:[2008-08-27T23:59:59.999Z TO *]
```

a sample url would be    localhost:8983/solr/select?q=yourdatefield:`[2008-08-27T23:59:59.999Z TO *`]

you want to submit the date part as a query so in the value of q like

```
localhost:8983/solr/select/q=(text:test+AND+indexed_at:`[2009-08-27T13:A15:A27.73Z TO *`])
```

So the entire query is contained within the q querystring paramter.

the format of the date is ISO 8601.

Comment: does it have to use IO?  why did you do  yourdatefield: and not yourdatefield=

Comment: IO you mean ISO? Yes it does that's the way SOLR formats dates. And the reason for using : instead of = is that = denotes the separation between a key and value in the HTTP context. where as : is the separation of a key and value in the SOLR context.

Comment: Olle, see my updates, it doesn't seem to be working.  I posted the retuned xml doc node if that helps?

Answer (score 2):

You can add a automatic timestamp to the documents as they are indexed using:

```
<field name="timestamp" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true" default="NOW" multiValued="false"/>
```

in the schema.xml.  The default schema has this commented out so if you copied the default, you just need to uncomment it.

You could add that and use olle's suggested search pattern to find the documents indexed after a certain date.  (You'd have to update *yourdatefield* with *timestamp* or whatever you name the field in the xml.

Comment: I don't see that in my schema.xml, i do have:     <fieldType name="date" class="solr.DateField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/> and    <field name="date" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" /> and    <field name="indexed_at" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true" default="NOW" multiValued="false"/>. and    <dynamicField name="*_dt" type="date"    indexed="true"  stored="true"/>

Comment: Yeah it would be the indexed_at field.

As for resolving your issue, I think olle clarified the answer correctly with putting the indexed_at:[start_date to *] in the q= part of your call.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a query that compares dates, here is the syntax for queries:
http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrQuerySyntax

And here is how you can make date comparisons in the query:
http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api/org/apache/solr/util/DateMathParser.html